# Handle NFC tag discovered event from a service

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

Well I'm trying to make an android service to handle NFC tag discovered events and do stuff in the background accordingly.

From what I've read here and there (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/K4JKF8iN0BI)

You can only handle those intents with an activity. Is there a way I could create a mock activity (ui less, much like a service) to handle this and then close the app and pass the just read nfc tag info to my service to perform what I want to be done in the background through the service?

THanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` in the activity's manifest entry.
This will effectively hide the activity.

Be aware that it will still be at the top of the stack so will take the click events and cause an onPause on any previous visible Activity.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that you cannot receive NFC intents in a background service, only an activity can do that. You can certainly do what you propose, with an invisible or transparent UI. I have no experience creating such an app, but I use [NFC Task Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) which behaves like you describe when I scan a tag that I have created with it.